# Property Not Found! same naming convention

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm here again asking a question, I've tried asking this a while ago (for today) but I've reconstructed my code. So, my problem is that when I click the button to show the details from the database, it show me an error that Property Not Found, I'm confused as to why this error pops out, Here is an example of the error, as you can see it can read the elements in the database when I sysout it, displaying it in the console [pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYn4C.png)
   )

```
     //empServlet
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    empServices empserv= new empServices();
    ArrayList <empGetSet> empgs = new ArrayList<empGetSet>();

    if (request.getParameter("process")!=null &&  request.getParameter("process").equals("showdis")) {

        empgs.addAll(empserv.getAll());
        request.setAttribute("empdet", empgs);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("showdet.jsp"); //forward to xxxpage after submit by button
        rd.forward(request,response);

    }

       //empServices
 package emppackage;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class empServices {

empServlet empservlet = new empServlet();
empDAO empdao = new empDAO();
public ArrayList <empGetSet> getAll() 
    {
        return empdao.getAllEmp();

    }

     //empDAO
    public ArrayList<empGetSet> getAllEmp()
  {

ArrayList<empGetSet> empdetails = new ArrayList<empGetSet>();

try {

    Connection conn = getConnection();
    String showsql = "SELECT *FROM csemp;";
    PreparedStatement psread= conn.prepareStatement(showsql);
    ResultSet rsread = psread.executeQuery();

    while (rsread.next()) 
    {

        empGetSet readgetset = new empGetSet();

        readgetset.setFname(rsread.getString(1));
        //System.out.println(readgetset.getFname());
        System.out.println(rsread.getString(1));
        readgetset.setLname(rsread.getString(2));
        readgetset.setNameRes(rsread.getString(3));
        readgetset.setSerials(rsread.getString(4));
        readgetset.setJrss(rsread.getString(5));
        readgetset.setBand(rsread.getString(6));
        readgetset.setAcct(rsread.getString(7));
        readgetset.setPMPs(rsread.getString(8));
        readgetset.setsJRSS(rsread.getString(9));
        readgetset.setOpenSeatDesc(rsread.getString(10));
        readgetset.setReqSkills(rsread.getString(11));
        readgetset.setReqBand(rsread.getString(12));
        readgetset.setDreject(rsread.getString(13));
        readgetset.setsRreject(rsread.getString(14));
        readgetset.setDetActPlan(rsread.getString(15));
        readgetset.setDataComplete(rsread.getString(16));
        readgetset.setStat(rsread.getString(17));


        empdetails.add(readgetset);

    }
    psread.close();
    conn.close();

}


catch (Exception e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}



return empdetails;


 }
```

This is my Getters and Setters with really the same naming convention
package emppackage;

```
   public class empGetSet {


private String Fname;
private String Lname;
private String NameRes;
private String Serials;
private String Jrss;
private String Band;
private String Acct;
private String PMPs;
private String sJRSS;
private String OpenSeatDesc;
private String ReqSkills;
private String ReqBand;
private String Dreject;
private String Rreject;
private String DetActPlan;
private String DataComplete;
private String Stat;



public String getFname() {

    return Fname;
}

public void setFname(String Fname) {

    this.Fname=Fname;
}

public String getLname() {

    return Lname;
}

public void setLname(String Lname) {

    this.Lname=Lname;
}

public String getNameRes() {

    return NameRes;
}

public void setNameRes(String NameRes) {

    this.NameRes=NameRes;
}

public String getSerials() {

    return Serials;
}

public void setSerials(String Serials) {

    this.Serials=Serials;
}

public String getJrss() {

    return Jrss;
}

public void setJrss(String Jrss) {

    this.Jrss=Jrss;
}

   public String getBand() {

    return Band;
}

public void setBand(String Band) {

    this.Band=Band;
}

public String getAcct() {

    return Acct;
}

public void setAcct(String Acct) {

    this.Acct=Acct;
}

public String getPMPs() {

    return PMPs;
}

public void setPMPs(String PMPs) {

    this.PMPs=PMPs;
}

public String getsJRSS() {

    return sJRSS;
}

public void setsJRSS(String sJRSS) {

    this.sJRSS=sJRSS;
}

public String getOpenSeatDesc() {

    return OpenSeatDesc;
}

public void setOpenSeatDesc(String OpenSeatDesc) {

    this.OpenSeatDesc=OpenSeatDesc;
}

 public String getReqSkills() {

    return ReqSkills;
}

public void setReqSkills(String ReqSkills) {

    this.ReqSkills=ReqSkills;
}

public String getReqBand() {

    return ReqBand;
}

public void setReqBand(String Acct) {

    this.Acct=Acct;
}

public String getDreject() {

    return Dreject;
}

public void setDreject(String Dreject) {

    this.Dreject=Dreject;
}

public String getRreject() {

    return Rreject;
}

public void setsRreject(String Rreject) {

    this.Rreject=Rreject;
}

public String getDetActPlan() {

    return DetActPlan;
}

public void setDetActPlan(String DetActPlan) {

    this.DetActPlan=DetActPlan;
}

   public String getDataComplete() {

    return DataComplete;
}

public void setDataComplete(String DataComplete) {

    this.DataComplete=DataComplete;
}

public String getStat() {

    return Stat;
}

public void setStat(String Stat) {

    this.Stat=Stat;
}


 }
```

This is my .jsp

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Show Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="right"><a href="loggedin.jsp"><button>Back</button></a></div>

    <form action ="empServlet" method="get">
    <table border =1 cellpadding="18">
    <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Name of Resource (LN ID Format)</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>JRSS</th>
    <th>Band</th>
    <th>Account (Proposed)</th>
    <th>PMP Seat</th>
    <th>Seat JRSS</th>
    <th>Open Seat Description</th>
    <th>Required Skills</th>
    <th>Required Band low/high</th>
    <th>Date of Rejection</th>
    <th>Reason for Rejection</th>
    <th>Detailed Action Plan</th>
    <th>Target Date of Completion</th>
    <th>Status(Ongoing/Closed)</th>
        <th colspan=2>Do This</th>


     </tr>
       </thead>

            <tbody>

        <c:forEach items ="${empdet}" var="empdet" >
            <tr>

                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Fname}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Lname}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.NameRes}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Serials}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Jrss}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Band}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Acct}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.PMPs}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.sJRSS}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.OpenSeatDesc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.ReqSkills}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.ReqBand}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Dreject}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Rreject}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.DetActPlan}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.DataComplete}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value ="${empdet.Stat}" /></td>
                <td><a href="empServlet?Serials=${empdet.Serials}&process=update">Update</a></td>
                <td><a href="empServlet?Serials=${empdet.Serials}&process=delete">Delete</a></td>

        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>

     </table>

     <br>
      <a href="empServlet?&process=showdis">Show All</a>



 </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: test replacing ${empdet.Fname} with ${empdet.fname}

Comment: can you pls explain why?

Comment: Instance variables should follow the lowerCamelCase naming convention. Not sure if this solves your problem at all but most libs/frameworks break at some time if you don't use the JavaBean convention.

Comment: you mean i should change the Fname at my setters and getters to fName, or something like that?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) and Google about JavaBeans.